# Can't run ./bin/kibana on ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I try to install Kibana 4 on Ubuntu 14.10 but whe i run ./bin/kibana, I have many error :

`./../node/bin/node: 1: ./../node/bin/node:ELF: not found
./../node/bin/node: 2: ./../node/bin/node: W: not found
./../node/bin/node: 2: ./../node/bin/node: -NE: not found
./../node/bin/node: 4: ./../node/bin/node: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Java 8, Elasticsearch and nodejs are installed,

Can you help me please ?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are not running it correctly.  How are you invoking it?

Comment: I download and untar kibana in /home then i run ./bin/kibana in /home/[Kibana folder untar]

Comment: Actually, it looks like `../node` contains something else than what Kibana expects.

Comment: Issue seems to be reported: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/3213

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs if the wrong architecture is used. E.g.

I first downloaded and installed `"kibana-4*-linux-x64.tar.gz"` blindly following a tutorial, while `"uname -a"` displayed :

> "Linux xubuntu-VirtualBox 3.2.0-90-generic #128-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 14
>   21:44:10 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux"

After replacing the kibana installation with the 32-bit version, everything worked fine.

Comment: Yes, I went on installing from the centos repo thereby, as documented here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/rpm.html and worked

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily solved using below steps

- Install nodejs, npm (nodejs has arm repositories)
- Dowload kibana binary and extract it
- change node path in `bin/kibana` to `NODE=/usr/bin/nodejs`

> Node path can be found by `which node` command