# Error Starting Kibana after install : kibana: 20: exec: /usr/bin/kibana-4.1.1-linux-x64/bin/../node/bin/node: not found

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I've just installed Kibana with the following steps:

```
 1. wget https://download.elastic.co/kibana/kibana/kibana-4.1.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
 2. tar -xvzf kibana-4.1.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
 3. mv kibana-4.1.1-linux-x64 /usr/bin
 4. cd /usr/bin
 5. ln -s kibana-4.1.1-linux-x64/bin/kibana kibana
 6. ./kibana
```

Kibana fails to start and I get:

```
kibana: 20: exec: /usr/bin/kibana-4.1.1-linux-x64/bin/../node/bin/node: not found
```

I've read that a mismatched architecture (64 bit vs 32 bit) could be causing this: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3146
But I am on 64 bit linux and am using the 64 bit version of Kibana

What is wrong?

Comment: which elastic and logstash version you are using with kibana 4.1.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Update: I've found the answer!
It is indeed because of an architecture mismatch. Even though I was on a 64 bit processor and OS, my version of Elasticsearch was 32 bit, which is what caused the problem.
I've switched to 32 bit Kibana and everything is working.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the same error trying to run Kibana on my Mac. Can you provide how you checked the bit version of your Elasticsearch? I installed both Elasticsearch and Kibana using Homebrew so I'm not quite sure which architecture was installed. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed my issue, so I figured I would post in case others faced the same problem. I uninstalled Kibana using `brew uninstall kibana --force` and then downloaded the 64 bit version of kibana from https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana and that version worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily solved using below steps

- Install nodejs, npm (nodejs has arm repositories)
- Dowload kibana binary and extract it
- change node path in `bin/kibana` to `NODE=/usr/bin/nodejs`

> Node path can be found by `which node` command

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53160093/5667202